# ASP.Net MVC Pass EF Data to a Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC and Entity Framework, and would like some assistance in passing data to a model so that I can make my view a strongly typed view and get the information out as I need.

In the about action in the home controller i want to pull out data from my SiteContent table that is for the About Page

```
        var sc = db.siteContents.Where( x => x.Page == "About").ToList();
        return View(sc);
```

A couple of questions I have around this, is first, how do I get this into my Model SiteContent

```
    public class SiteContent
{
    public int ContentId { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public string Page { get; set; }
    public string ContentHeader { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime OriginalPostDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatePostDate { get; set; }
    public string ImageFileName { get; set; }
    public bool ContentReleased { get; set; }
}
```

I am uncertain on how I should proceed from here.

The from here I would like to use a strongly typed view to get the data by using my model.

Any and all help very much appreciated.

Thanks

Simon

Comment: Are you wanting a collection of `SiteContent` (which is what you currently have) of a single `SiteContent` object?

Comment: Is `SiteContent` the model used in your `DbContext` or is this a POCO? Also, you're pulling a list (`.ToList`); did you mean to grab `SingleOrDefault()`?

Comment: So you can easily do that by using `IEnumerable<SiteContent>` as a model for your view.

Comment: @BradChristie yes, siteContext is used in my DbContext ` public virtual DbSet<siteContent> siteContents { get; set; }`

Comment: @SirwanAfifi i thought i would want an IEnumerable, but dont know how I should implement it

Comment: @StephenMuecke in the about page there are a number of "sections" that will need to be managed such as "About Mike", "Qualifications", "Goals" which is why im bringing back a list of objects

Comment: Your model is `IEnumerable<SiteContent>` so in your view you need `@model IEnumerable<SiteContent>` and then a `foreach` loop to generate the html for each item in the collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your view like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<SiteContent>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>ContentType</td>
      // other data
   </tr>
   @foreach(var item in Model)
   {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.ContentType</td>
            // other data
        <tr>
   }
</table>
```

Comment: using this example i get this error back "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[InspireFitnessForAll.WebSite.DataModel.siteContent]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[InspireFitnessForAll.WebSite.Models.SiteContent]'."

Comment: Check your namespace for SiteContent, It seems that your are accessing `SiteContent` in your `DataModel` folder not `Models`

Comment: ive just renamed the model to PageContent and have the same issue.

Comment: think i may have just spotted my mistake

Comment: Thank you for your help.